# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED'

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9

i logged into magento dashboard,in sales/orders the list of orders are displaying but when I click any of the link then its giving this error

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant
>   'ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED'

Answer (score 0):

There was an update in Magento 1.8 that changed `viewAction` in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php` to call `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED`.  In Magento 1.7, this wasn't the case.

This change relates to a constant added to `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` - `const ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED= 'product_permission_denied';` which is on line 359.

I'd guess, in this instance, that you've updated from one version of Magento to another, and updated one file, but not the other.  Please ensure that both are updated in core.  Alternatively, something is rewriting `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and hasn't (or has incorrectly) implemented the constant.